Ошибка в telegram боте : *ImportError: cannot import name
У меня есть телеграмм бот и база данных для него (тоже код) что делать при ошибке:
ImportError: cannot import name 'add_client' from 'booking_db' (E:\My Files\Desktop\booking_db.py)?
вот основной код тг бота:
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler, filters
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from booking_db import add_client  # Изменён импорт на новое название файла
import random
import string
import io
import json
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

API_TOKEN = 'Y7644376558:AAHhPTRvS3Zyxmpbl0stYwUjKGMzVuWN5Y4'

# Conversation states
NAME, SURNAME, PATRONYMIC, START_DATE, END_DATE, CAPTCHA, ADDRESS = range(7)

# File to store booked dates
BOOKED_DATES_FILE = "booked_dates_main_bot.json"

# Load booked dates from file
def load_booked_dates():
    try:
        with open(BOOKED_DATES_FILE, "r") as file:
            return set(datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").date() for date in json.load(file))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return set()

# Save booked dates to file
def save_booked_dates(booked_dates):
    with open(BOOKED_DATES_FILE, "w") as file:
        json.dump([date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for date in booked_dates], file)

# Store booked dates in memory
booked_dates = load_booked_dates()

# Function to create the calendar with available and booked dates
def create_calendar(year, month, min_date=None):
    now = datetime.now()
    today = now.date()
    calendar_buttons = [[InlineKeyboardButton(f"{year} - {month:02d}", callback_data="IGNORE")]]
    days_of_week = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"]
    calendar_buttons.append([InlineKeyboardButton(day, callback_data="IGNORE") for day in days_of_week])

    first_day = datetime(year, month, 1)
    last_day = (first_day + timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
    calendar_rows = []
    row = []

    for _ in range(first_day.weekday()):
        row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(" ", callback_data="IGNORE"))

    for day in range(1, last_day.day + 1):
        current_date = datetime(year, month, day).date()

        # If the date is booked, mark it as unavailable
        if current_date in booked_dates:
            row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(f"{day} ", callback_data="IGNORE"))
        else:
            row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(str(day), callback_data=f"BOOK-{year}-{month:02d}-{day:02d}"))

        if len(row) == 7:
            calendar_rows.append(row)
            row = []
    if row:
        calendar_rows.append(row)

    navigation_buttons = [
        InlineKeyboardButton("<", callback_data=f"PREV-{year}-{month:02d}"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Cancel", callback_data="CANCEL"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(">", callback_data=f"NEXT-{year}-{month:02d}")
    ]
    calendar_rows.append(navigation_buttons)

    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(calendar_buttons + calendar_rows)

# Generate random captcha
def generate_captcha():
    captcha_text = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=6))
    img = Image.new('RGB', (200, 80), color=(255, 255, 255))
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.load_default()
    d.text((10, 25), captcha_text, font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
    byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(byte_arr, format='PNG')
    byte_arr.seek(0)
    return byte_arr, captcha_text

# Start the conversation
async def start(update: Update, context):
    context.user_data.clear()

    keyboard = [
        ["Просто забронировать"],
        ["Wi-Fi", "Куда пойти"],
        ["У меня проблема", "Оставить отзыв"],
        ["Доп. услуги", "Помощь"]
    ]
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=False)
    await update.message.reply_text("Добро пожаловать в бот для апартаментов! Выберите нужную опцию:", reply_markup=reply_markup)

# Booking process
async def get_name(update: Update, context):
    context.user_data['name'] = update.message.text
    await update.message.reply_text("Введите вашу фамилию:")
    return SURNAME

async def get_surname(update: Update, context):
    context.user_data['surname'] = update.message.text
    await update.message.reply_text("Введите ваше отчество:")
    return PATRONYMIC

async def get_patronymic(update: Update, context):
    context.user_data['patronymic'] = update.message.text
    now = datetime.now()
    await update.message.reply_text("Выберите дату начала бронирования:", reply_markup=create_calendar(now.year, now.month))
    return START_DATE

async def select_date(update: Update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    data = query.data

    if data.startswith("BOOK-"):
        _, year, month, day = data.split("-")
        selected_date = datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day)).date()

        if 'start_date' not in context.user_data:
            context.user_data['start_date'] = selected_date
            await query.edit_message_text(f"Дата начала бронирования: {selected_date}\nТеперь выберите дату окончания бронирования.")
            await query.message.reply_text("Выберите дату окончания бронирования:", reply_markup=create_calendar(selected_date.year, selected_date.month))
            return END_DATE
        else:
            start_date = context.user_data['start_date']
            if selected_date < start_date:
                await query.answer("Дата окончания не может быть раньше даты начала!", show_alert=True)
                return END_DATE

            if (selected_date - start_date).days > 6:
                await query.answer("Продолжительность бронирования не может превышать 6 дней!", show_alert=True)
                return END_DATE

            context.user_data['end_date'] = selected_date
            temp_date = start_date

            while temp_date <= selected_date:
                booked_dates.add(temp_date)
                temp_date += timedelta(days=1)

            save_booked_dates(booked_dates)
            await query.edit_message_text(f"Дата окончания бронирования: {selected_date}")
            captcha_image, captcha_text = generate_captcha()
            context.user_data['captcha'] = captcha_text
            await query.message.reply_photo(photo=captcha_image, caption="Введите символы с изображения:")
            return CAPTCHA

    elif data == "CANCEL":
        await query.edit_message_text(text="Выбор даты отменён.")
        return ConversationHandler.END

    return START_DATE if 'start_date' not in context.user_data else END_DATE

async def captcha_verification(update: Update, context):
    user_captcha = update.message.text
    if user_captcha != context.user_data['captcha']:
        await update.message.reply_text("Неправильная капча. Попробуйте ещё раз.")
        return CAPTCHA

    await update.message.reply_text("Введите номер вашей квартиры:")
    return ADDRESS

async def save_booking(update: Update, context):
    apartment_number = update.message.text
    start_date = context.user_data['start_date']
    end_date = context.user_data['end_date']

    add_client(
        telegram_user_id=update.message.chat_id,
        full_name=context.user_data['name'],
        patronymic=context.user_data['patronymic'],
        booking_start_date=start_date,
        booking_end_date=end_date,
        apartment_number=apartment_number,
        phone_number="1234567890"  # Например, можно добавить поле для телефона
    )
    await update.message.reply_text("Ваша бронь успешно сохранена!")
    return ConversationHandler.END

def main():
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(API_TOKEN).build()

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
        states={
            NAME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, get_name)],
            SURNAME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, get_surname)],
            PATRONYMIC: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, get_patronymic)],
            START_DATE: [CallbackQueryHandler(select_date)],
            END_DATE: [CallbackQueryHandler(select_date)],
            CAPTCHA: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, captcha_verification)],
            ADDRESS: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, save_booking)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", lambda update, context: ConversationHandler.END)]
    )

    app.add_handler(conv_handler)
    app.run_polling()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

вот код базы данных:
import sqlite3 as sq 
 
# Создаем базу данных и таблицу, если она не существует 
def create_db(): 
    with sq.connect("goyda.db") as con: 
        cur = con.cursor() 
        # Создание таблицы "clients" с добавлением поля для telegram_user_id 
        cur.execute(""" 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients ( 
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
            telegram_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
            full_name TEXT NOT NULL, 
            patronymic TEXT NOT NULL, 
            booking_start_date TEXT NOT NULL, 
            booking_end_date TEXT NOT NULL, 
            apartment_number INTEGER NOT NULL, 
            phone_number TEXT NOT NULL 
        ) 
        """) 
        con.commit() 
 
# Вызов функции для создания базы данных и таблицы 
create_db()

помогите пожалуйста

Логичный вопрос - что такое add_client?
